# How to detect when the chrome devtools is closed and trigger a function in background.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, onbeforeunload

I'm currently writing a chrome extension that has it's own panel in the Devtools. Although I'm facing an issue. I'm trying to trigger some action in the background page when the Devtools panel of a specific tab is closed.

I tried adding this to devtools.js :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  port.postMessage({action: 'disableTab', tabId: tabID});
  return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
};
```

Although the confirmation is never displayed and the message is never posted.

I think that it's because my devtools.html / devtools.js file isn't the one that is handling the main Devtools panel. it' only appended to it, something like that.

I'm still searching for an answer, anyone knows how I could achieve that ?

**Edit:**
I just noticed that this app is doing exactly what I want! https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions
Run an analysis, then try closing the devtools, you'll be prompted.

Comment: In one of my extensions, I establish a connection from the panel to the event page. When the devtools is closed, port.onDisconnect fires.